# Rust, how do i correctly free heap allocated memory?

Tags: pointers, rust, heap-memory

I wanted to reinvent the wheel(reference counting smart pointer) and i am not sure how to properly free the memory leaked with `Box::into_raw()` , once the references go to zero i don't know how to efficiently free the memory that is being pointed

I originally went with

```
impl<T> Drop for SafePtr<T>{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        //println!("drop, {} refs", self.get_refs());
        self.dec_refs();
        let ref_count = self.get_refs();
        if ref_count == 0usize{
            unsafe{
                let _ = Box::from_raw(self.ptr);
                let _ = Box::from_raw(self.refs);
            };
            println!("Dropped all pointed values");
        };
    }
}
```

but i was wondering if `ptr::drop_in_place()` would work the same if not better since it won't have to make a Box just to drop it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation on [`into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw) just `drop_in_place` is not enough, to free the memory you also have to call `dealloc`:

> ```rust
> use std::alloc::{dealloc, Layout};
> use std::ptr;
>
> let x = Box::new(String::from("Hello"));
> let p = Box::into_raw(x);
> unsafe {
>     ptr::drop_in_place(p);
>     dealloc(p as *mut u8, Layout::new::<String>());
> }
> ```

For performance considerations, both methods [compile to the exact same instructions](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/Kv8snv91o), so I'd just use `drop(Box::from_raw(ptr))` to save me the hussle remembering the `dealloc` where applicable.

Comment: That's exactly what i wasn't sure about. Thanks for the help i'll stick with drop(Box::from_raw(ptr)) then!